# Delete all characters that come after a given string

Tags: python

how exactly can I delete characters after .jpg? is there a way to differentiate between the extension I take with python and what follows?
for example I have a link like that

```
https://s13emagst.akamaized.net/products/29146/29145166/images/res_cd1fa80f252e88faa70ffd465c516741.jpg10DCC3DD9E74DC1D10104F623D7E9BDC
```

How can I delete everything after .jpg?
I tried replacing but it didn't work
another way?
Use a forum to count strings or something like ?
I tried to get jpg files with this

```
for link in links:
            res = requests.get(link).text
            soup = BeautifulSoup(res, 'html.parser')
            img_links = []
            for img in soup.select('a.thumbnail img[src]'):
                print(img["src"])
                with open('links'+'.csv', 'a', encoding = 'utf-8', newline='') as csv_file:
                    file_is_empty = os.stat(self.filename+'.csv').st_size == 0
                    fieldname = ['links']
                    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames = fieldname)
                    if file_is_empty:
                        writer.writeheader()
                    writer.writerow({'links':img["src"]})

                img_links.append(img["src"])
```

Comment: Please provide the code that you have tried.

Comment: @ch2019 done i put code

Comment: What part of your code is relevant to the question? You ask how to remove a part of a string and post 10 lines of code which do all kinds of things and don't even work when copied into an editor (imports and `links` are missing and also irrelevant).

Answer (score 1):

You could use split (assuming the string has 'jpg', otherwise the code below will just return the original url).

```
string = 'https://s13emagst.akamaized.net/products/29146/29145166/images/res_cd1fa80f252e88faa70ffd465c516741.jpg10DCC3DD9E74DC1D10104F623D7E9BDC'
jpg_removed = string.split('.jpg')[0]+'.jpg'
```

Example

```
string = 'www.google.com'
com_removed = string.split('.com')[0] 
# com_removed = 'www.google'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of regular expression. You just want to ignore the characters after .jpg so you can some use of something like this:

```
import re
new_url=re.findall("(.*\.jpg).*",old_url)[0]
```

`(.*\.jpg)` is like a capturing group where you're matching any number of characters before .jpg. Since `.` has a special meaning you need to escape the `.` in jpg with a `\`. `.*` is used to match any number of character but since this is not inside the capturing group `()` this will get matched but won't get extracted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .find function to find the characters .jpg then you can index the string to get everything but that. Ex:

```
string = https://s13emagst.akamaized.net/products/29146/29145166/images/res_cd1fa80f252e88faa70ffd465c516741.jpg10DCC3DD9E74DC1D10104F623D7E9BDC
index = string.find(".jpg")
new_string = string[:index+ 4]
```

You have to add four because that is the length of jpg so it does not delete that too.

Answer (score 0):

The `find()` method returns the lowest index of the substring if it is found in given string. If its is not found then it returns -1.

```
str ='https://s13emagst.akamaized.net/products/29146/29145166/images/res_cd1fa80f252e88faa70ffd465c516741.jpg10DCC3DD9E74DC1D10104F623D7E9BDC'
result = str.find('jpg')
print(result)
new_str = str[:result]

print(new_str+'jpg')
```

Answer (score 0):

See: [Extracting extension from filename in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541390/extracting-extension-from-filename-in-python)

Instead of extracting the extension, we extract the filename and add the extension (if we know it's always .jpg, it's fine!)

```
import os
filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext('/path/to/somefile.jpg_corruptedpath')
result = filename + '.jpg'
```

Now, outside of the original question, I think there might be something wrong with how you got that piece of information int he first place. There must be a better way to extract that jpeg without messing around with the path. Sadly I can't help you with that since I a novice with BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression to replace everything after .jpg with an empty string:

```
import re

url  ='https://s13emagst.akamaized.net/products/29146/29145166/images/res_cd1fa80f252e88faa70ffd465c516741.jpg10DCC3DD9E74DC1D10104F623D7E9BDC'

name = re.sub(r'(?<=\.jpg).*',"",url)

print(name)
https://s13emagst.akamaized.net/products/29146/29145166/images/res_cd1fa80f252e88faa70ffd465c516741.jpg
```