# How to extract only the filename from the link python

Tags: python, path, filenames

I have the following link:
`'//mypath/link1/link2/link3/link4/this is the folder\\123456 (2).txt'`

I would like to extract the path+sub directory separately, filename with extension and filename without extension. The output should look like the following:

```
[//mypath/link1/link2/link3/link4/this is the folder, 123456 (2).txt, 123456]
```

What I tried so far?

```py
import os
pth = '//mypath/link1/link2/link3/link4/this is the folder\\123456 (2).txt'
head, tail = os.path.split(pth)
print([head, tail])
```

I was able to extract the path and filename but not the filename without extension. How do I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extracting extension from filename in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541390/extracting-extension-from-filename-in-python)

Comment: No, it extracts the file extensions and not the filename. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `string.split()` two times.

```
pth = '//mypath/link1/link2/link3/link4/this is the folder\\123456 (2).txt'
path,filename = pth.split('\\')
file_no_ex = filename.split(' ')[0]
output = [path,filename,file_no_ex]
```

Output:

`['//mypath/link1/link2/link3/link4/this is the folder', '123456 (2).txt', '123456']`