# How to ask for filename whilst adding today's date and time in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, filenames

I have written the code for automation of creating file with date and time format. So, the file output would be

**Product_Name-date**

From this code:

```
filename = datetime.now().strftime('Product_Name-%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M.csv')
with open(filename, "w+") as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(["Name", "Price"])
    for d in datas: csv_output.writerow(d)
```

However, I want to ask for input from user to manually name each file. To become:

**UserInputProduct_Name**-date

I've read the tutorial from W3School, but I can't implement it correctly.

```
 filename = input("Input the Filename: ")
 f_extns = filename.split(".")
 print ("The extension of the file is : " + repr(f_extns[-1]))
```

How do I do that?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? `f_extns[-1]` *is* the (last) extension, assuming the file name has an extension.

Comment: You probably don't want a full file name, just a "stem" to which you'll append the date and `.csv`: `stem = input(); filename = datetime.now().strftime(f'{stem}-%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M.csv')`.

Comment: You can also just strip `.csv` from the user input if you are worried about it being duplicated.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not too familiar with the syntax, currently learning Python from scratch. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```
Product_Name = input("Input the Filename: ")
filename = datetime.now().strftime(f'{Product_Name}-%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M.csv')
with open(filename, "w+") as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(["Name", "Price"])
    for d in datas: csv_output.writerow(d)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works, I didn't know it was a simple "Product_Name = input" function.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got your question right, but here is what I think you are looking for.

```
Product_Name = input("Enter filename: ")
filename = datetime.now().strftime('{}-%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M.csv').format(Product_Name)
with open(filename, "w+") as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(["Name", "Price"])
    for d in datas:
        csv_output.writerow(d)
```

After testing this code myself, I got file named:

> test-2021-07-03-16-30.csv

Comment: It does work too! Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

As bera TV have answered, that is the solution according to your First question

I assume that your second question is to "get the extention of a file"

Which is a possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541390/extracting-extension-from-filename-in-py)

As a Solution, you can use the pathlib avilable in python 3.x

```
>>> import pathlib
>>> x = pathlib.PurePosixPath("C:\\Path\\To\\File\\myfile.exten").suffix
>>> print(x)
".exten"
```

Comment: Hi. I suppose my question might be confusing. But, I'm trying to ask for user input to name the file, which Bera TV and mortex already answered correctly according to my needs. Anyway, thanks for the answer. Might need that later in the future.

Comment: Great then, I thought your second code was to ask for the extension as you are accessing the last element using [-1]. Sorry for the misunderstanding, Have a nice day

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion too. I'm very new to Python, so I might not understand some syntax that I'm using. After all, everything that I've learned might have resulted from trial and error without fully knowing the syntax. Cheers!