# Rename multiple files with multiple extensions

Tags: python, csv, file-rename

I have this python script which will take these three arguments:

1. a given path for a directory with files to rename
2. a CSV file with two columns to map the file names to:

```
original,new
barcode01,sample01
barcode02,sample02
```

3. extension of the file (i.e. .txt, .bam, .png, .txt.readdb.log) which can be long.

The script:

```
import os
import csv

def rename_files(path, name_map, ext):
    with open(name_map, 'r') as csv_map:
        filereader = csv.DictReader(csv_map)
        for row in filereader:
            original_name = row["original"]
            new_name = row["new"]
            old_filename = '%s/%s.%s' % (path, original_name, ext)
            new_filename = '%s/%s_%s.%s' % (path, new_name, original_name, ext)
            try:
                os.rename(old_filename, new_filename)
            except Exception as e:
                print('Rename for file %s failed. Details: ' % old_filename) 
                print (e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    filename, path, name_map, ext = sys.argv
    rename_files(path, name_map, ext)
```

For example:

```
python rename.py /test/directory filestorename.csv txt
```

will only rename barcode01.txt to sample01.txt.

However, there are multiple barcode01 files with different extensions (i.e. barcode01.png). Instead of passing these extensions as arguments to the script, how can I modify this script to just rename all these files at once, keeping the extension the same?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541390/extracting-extension-from-filename-in-python

Comment: @Robson Thank you. I have fixed it and added the filename in the example.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all files exists, you may extract the base directory, basename and file extension as follows:

```
from csv import DictReader
from os import path, rename
from sys import exit

import argparse

def rename_file(row):
    origin = row['original']
    directory = path.dirname(origin)
    _, extension = path.splitext(path.basename(origin))
    target = path.join(directory, '{}{}'.format(row['new'], extension))
    return rename(origin, target)
```

call it inside a loop:

```
def rename_files(spreadsheet):
    csv = DictReader(open(spreadsheet))
    valid_rows = filter(lambda row: path.isfile(row['original']), csv)
    for row in valid_rows:
        rename_file(row)
```

You also may improve your `main` function:

```
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser('rename files from *.csv')
    parser.add_argument(
        '-f', '--file',
        metavar='file',
        type=str,
        help='csv (comma-separated values) file'
    )

    args = parser.parse_args()

    if not path.isfile(args.file):
        print('No such file: {}'.format(args.file))
        return exit(1)

    return rename_files(args.file)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! How do I modify this to handle longer extensions (i.e. sample01.alignreport.txt or sample01.pass.vcf.gz versus just sample01.txt). This works but ends up only including the end suffix of the extension.

Comment: This is not a _longer file extension_, but rather a compressed file. If you are working with Pandas, you should use `pd.read_csv` function with `compression` parameter.

Comment: Are you renaming files without considering their actual encoding? Keep in mind that `*.csv` and `*.tsv` are just for loading datasets, while `*.vcf` for contacts. Files `*.bz`, `*.gz`, `*.rar`, and `*.zip` are just compressed files or folders.

Comment: I want to rename the files while maintaining the extension in full regardless of the encoding. The files range from CSV/TSV, *.txt, to compressed BAM/SAM files. There are some `*.gz` with varying suffixes (i.e. "*.pass.vcf.gz", "merged.vcf.gz"). This current method will rename with the same encoding (i.e. *.gz) while removing the descriptive suffix (i.e. *.pass.vcf.gz).

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `pathlib` library, which makes dealing with file name easier. Note that in `pathlib`, a file name without extension is called a *stem*.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import csv
import pathlib
import sys


def rename_files(directory, name_map):
    directory = pathlib.Path(directory)

    with open(name_map) as stream:
        reader = csv.reader(stream)
        next(reader)  # Skip the header
        for old_name, new_name in reader:
            for old_path in directory.glob(old_name + ".*"):
                new_path = old_path.with_stem(new_name)
                old_path.rename(new_path)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    rename_files(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
```

Example:

```
python rename.py /test/directory filestorename.csv
```

#### Notes

- The key to rename files, regardless of extension, is to use the `.glob()` function to find all files with the same name, but with different extensions.
- The `.with_stem()` function basically take the path and return another path with different *stem* (filename minus extension)