# Get the extension of uploaded file in flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm writing a flask API to extract text from the document. I want to check the extension and if it is pdf I'll give it to the pdf miner else docx2txt.

```
@app.route('/text-extraction', methods = ['POST'])
def text_extractions():
    f = request.files['files']
    split_tup = os.path.splitext(f)
    file_extension = split_tup[1]
    if file_extension == '.pdf':
        return extract_text(f)
    else:
        text = docx2txt.process(f)
    if extract_text:
        return text.replace('\t', ' ')
    return None
```

Comment: This might be the Solution your looking for:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541390/extracting-extension-from-filename-in-python

Comment: `endswith('.pdf')` ?

Comment: Or here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext

Comment: endswith('.pdf') is not working in my case @QwertYou

Comment: hm, what is the error and how do you do this?