# How to make tkinter button call two different function depending on filetype?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created file dialog window with tkinter and two different functions: one works with images, another with videos. How can I make tkinter button to call different functions when either of filetypes passed into file dialog.

Comment: Make a function that checks the filetype and calls one or the other accordingly. Attach that to button.

Comment: Could you please show me how to make that function?

Comment: check the file extension. You can do this with the `os` standard library. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/541394/9267296) for reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply write a function that will check the extension and act accordigly:

```
def fun(filename):
    if filename.endswith(".txt"):
        fun_txt(filename)
    else:
        fun_doc(filename)
```