# Filter specified file extensions to other file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have many files in different paths with various file extensions.

My `input.txt` content as follows,

```
/path/to/dir1/readme.html
/path/to/dir1/file.c
/path/to/dir1/file1.c
/path/to/dir1/a.html
/path/to/dir2/abc.java
/path/to/dir1/sample.js
/path/to/dir2/a.bin
/path/to/dir1/as.json
.......................
...........................
..............................
```

I need to filter and move the specified extension files from all occurrences of `input.txt` file to `output.txt` file.

For this, i have below script.

```py
import shutil

input_file = 'input.txt'
output_file = 'output.txt'

file_extensions = ['.html', '.c', '.cpp', '.h', '.py', '.txt', '.js', '.json', '.csv']

with open(input_file, 'r') as input_file, open(output_file, 'w') as output_file:
    for line in input_file:
        file_path = line.strip()

        if any(file_path.endswith(ext) for ext in file_extensions):
            output_file.write(file_path + '\n')
            shutil.move(file_path, file_path + '.processed')

    print('Matching file moved to output.txt.')
```

Expected `output.txt` should be like below.

```
/path/to/dir1/readme.html
/path/to/dir1/file.c
/path/to/dir1/file1.c
/path/to/dir1/sample.js
/path/to/dir1/as.json
```

Above script doesn't work, it fails with below errors

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 791, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/path/to/dir1/readme.html' -> '/path/to/dir1/readme.html.processed'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "split_src_libs.py", line 24, in <module>
    shutil.move(file_path, file_path + '.processed')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 811, in move
    copy_function(src, real_dst)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 435, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 264, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc, open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/path/to/dir1/readme.html'
```

What is causing this issue?

Any help would be appreciated to filter & move the files to `output.txt` file.

Note: Moved files shouldn't be exist in `input.txt` file.

Comment: You're trying to move the files but they can't be found. Sure they exist and Python script can move them?

Comment: Since i'm trying to move the matched extension files from my `input.txt` to `output.txt` file. So in my `input.txt` i have `/path/to/dir1/readme.html` file.

Comment: The error message seems pretty explicit! In addition, the line causing an error isn't relevant to the goal you explained; furthermore, your expected output doesn't match your specifications (why shouldn't `/path/to/dir1/a.html` be in output,txt, for example?)

Comment: Yea but your moving them on your file system to have '. processed' behind the filename, but that fails. So the script can't find them.

Comment: ah it just need to search in `input.txt` file if matched extension files found. it just need to moved to `output.txt` file.

Comment: Do you want to move (or copy) the file_path line, or the file itself? This is quite unclear.

Comment: So you don't actually want to rename the file on your system?

Comment: I want move the matched extension files from my `input.txt` file to `output.txt` file.

Comment: right. i dont want to rename them.

Comment: Then the `shutil...` line shouldn't exist.

Comment: You're missing `/path/to/dir1/a.html` in your expected output since `.html` is in your list.

Answer (score 1):

`shutil.move` moves/renames the file on your filesystem.

That fails, probably because the file does not exist, or the python script does not have permission to move it.

---

If you just want to append the name to `output.txt`, remove the `shutil` line.

```
input_file = 'input.txt'
output_file = 'output.txt'

file_extensions = ['.html', '.c', '.cpp', '.h', '.py', '.txt', '.js', '.json', '.csv']

with open(input_file, 'r') as input_file, open(output_file, 'w') as output_file:
    for line in input_file:
        file_path = line.strip()

        if any(file_path.endswith(ext) for ext in file_extensions):
            output_file.write(file_path + '\n')

    print('Matching file moved to output.txt.')
```

Now if I run the script, the output.txt contains:

```
/path/to/dir1/readme.html
/path/to/dir1/file.c
/path/to/dir1/file1.c
/path/to/dir1/a.html
/path/to/dir1/sample.js
/path/to/dir1/as.json
```

---

That said, consider using the following, using `os.path.splitext` to get the file extension, then you can just do an `if ext in file_extensions`, so you don't need the `any` and loop:

```py
import os

input_file = 'input.txt'
output_file = 'output.txt'

file_extensions = ['.html', '.c', '.cpp', '.h', '.py', '.txt', '.js', '.json', '.csv']

with open(input_file, 'r') as input_file, open(output_file, 'w') as output_file:
    for line in input_file:
        filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(line.strip())

        if file_extension in file_extensions:
            output_file.write(line)

    print('Matching file moved to output.txt.')
```

- [Extracting extension from filename in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541390/extracting-extension-from-filename-in-python)

Comment: it moved all the files. didn't consider my specified file extensions.

Comment: Oeps, had a typo in the second code block. Fixed now.

Comment: @0stone0: it seems you forgot the last file (.json) in your output.txt listing; that said, both codes yield the correct output :)

Comment: Did it work for you @user4948798?

Comment: @0stone0 - I have many files in my input.txt file, but your script copying the specified extension files to output.txt instead of moving them.

Comment: [You said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76489042/search-and-move-the-specified-extension-to-other-file/76489146?noredirect=1#comment134866564_76489042) that you didn't want to move the files.

Comment: No, i want filter based on provided file extension and move those files to `output.txt` file from my `input.txt` file.

Comment: Oke, then I still don't understand whats going wrong. The output.txt contains only those files from input.txt which extension matches your list. Please let me know what (which line) doesn't work for you.

Comment: Actually i have 12 Lakhs files in my `input.txt` file from that your script filtered and copying them to `output.txt` file instead of moving those files. Please help me to move them.

Comment: Dude, please keep it clear. Your last message is contradicting. Currently, the filesnames are saved in `output.txt`, **and are NOT moved or altered in any way**. What's missing??

Comment: Files are `Not moved`

Comment: What's that support to mean? Do they need to be moved? As you said they shouldn't. I give up, good luck m8

Comment: yes right `['.html', '.c', '.cpp', '.h', '.py', '.txt', '.js', '.json', '.csv']` extension files need to moved to `output.txt` file.

Comment: Yes thats what happening, as already stated many times.

Comment: Though this is FAR from clear, I think (or rather guess) that the OP wants the entries "moved" to output.txt to be deleted from input.txt ; could you (@user4948798) confirm this is the case, and if so edit your question to make it clear?

Comment: Yes you are right, I want the entries to be moved to output.txt, after moving it shouldn't exist in input.txt file.

Comment: Ahhh, now it makes sense. That's not a lot of changes since you already know the line. I'm away from my PC now but I'll try to update my answer later this evening.

Answer (score -1):

As was said earlier, the error comes from the `file` you tried to move not existing.

But since you don't need to actually move the files, only to filter your input file, no need for `shutil.move`. Here's a working solution, updated to rewrite input.txt with only the unmoved lines:

```
input_file = 'input.txt'
output_file = 'output.txt'
file_extensions = ['.html', '.c', '.cpp', '.h', '.py', '.txt', '.js', '.json', '.csv']

unmoved_lines = []

with open(input_file, 'r') as _input_file, open(output_file, 'w') as output_file:
    for line in _input_file:
        if f'.{line.strip().split(".")[-1]}' in file_extensions:
            output_file.write(line)
        else:
            unmoved_lines.append(line)
            
with open(input_file, 'w') as _input_file:
    _input_file.write(''.join(unmoved_lines))
```

output.txt:

```
/path/to/dir1/readme.html
/path/to/dir1/file.c
/path/to/dir1/file1.c
/path/to/dir1/a.html
/path/to/dir1/sample.js
/path/to/dir1/as.json
```

input.txt:

```
/path/to/dir2/abc.java
/path/to/dir2/a.bin
```