# How to extract the extension from a file path

Tags: python, string, lowercase

I have a file path stored as a string in Python, and I need to extract the extension from it. If anyone can share the simplest way to accomplish this task using Python suggestions or code examples I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank You!! :)

Comment: Thank you so much Pete, Ali, Nethmi, and Ananya this really helped! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

```
import pathlib

pathlib.Path("abc.txt").suffix

>>> '.txt'
```

You'll find more info on pathlib also [here](https://realpython.com/python-pathlib/).

Answer (score 0):

Use [os.path.splitext](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext):

```py
import os
file_name, file_ext = os.path.splitext('/path/to/somefile.ext')
print(file_name) # prints '/path/to/somefile'
print(file_ext)  # prints '.ext'
```

Comment: This question is already answered before, you can refer to this topic [Extracting extension from filename in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541390/extracting-extension-from-filename-in-python#541394)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the **os.path** module, specifically the **splitext()** function.

```
import os

file_path = "/path/to/file.txt"
file_extension = os.path.splitext(file_path)[1]

print(file_extension)  # Output: ".txt"
```

The **os.path.splitext()** function splits the file path into the base name and the extension. The function returns a tuple where the first element is the base name and the second element is the extension, including the dot ('.') prefix. In the example above, **file_extension** will contain the value **".txt"**.

By using **os.path.splitext()**, you can handle various file path formats correctly, such as **/path/to/file.txt**, **/path/to/file.tar.gz**, or even **file.txt** without a specific path.

Comment: [don't answer duplicate questions](/help/how-to-answer). find what they're duplicates of, and flag them as [duplicates](/help/duplicates).